# Editing Strings in a Pandas Dataframe

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, string, data-cleaning

I have a pandas dataframe like the following:

```
Date   Title 
Jan 1  Washington Running
Jan 2  Jefferson City Cycling
Jan 3  Springfield Running
...
```

How can I remove the word "Running" or "Cycling" from all of the titles? I would like to get:

```
Date   Title 
Jan 1  Washington
Jan 2  Jefferson City
Jan 3  Springfield
...
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll want to use pandas's string modifiers. Here are the [docs](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.replace.html) for `pandas.Series.str.replace()`. It is slightly faster than the normal replace.

Mechanical_meat's great one line approach works with `.str.replace()` also:

```
df['Title'].str.replace(r'(\bRunning\b|\bCycling\b)','',regex=True)
```

I thought I'd offer the alternative of using `df['Title'].str.replace('Running','')` and `df['Title'].str.replace('Cycling','')`. Why do it in two steps? It avoids regex which can be "costly". Running a `timeit` on the two for small dataframes though finds the overhead of running replace twice is significantly higher than the cost of regex. I'd imagine it only gets worse for larger dataframes.