# Cut each string in a pandas dataframe

Tags: pandas, string, dataframe, cut

I have a Dataframe 'country' like this:

```
Booking date            Country1 Country2 Country3                                 Country 4
2023-07-08T00:00:00.000 NaN      NaN      129.6119.7449.3519.7439.4819             13.018.614
2023-07-89T00:00:00.000 NaN      NaN      19.7439.4849.3516.09.8739.4834.4819.7419 67.518.616.557.629
```

I would like to have:

```
Booking date            Country1 Country2 Country3 Country4
2023-07-08T00:00:00.000 NaN      NaN      129.61   13.02
2023-07-89T00:00:00.000 NaN      NaN      19.74    67.52
```

So basically, I want to cut each string in a pandas DataFrame to three decimals after the first point and then round it to two decimals. How do I go about doing this?

I have tried what I found here: [Editing Strings in a Pandas Dataframe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64885222/editing-strings-in-a-pandas-dataframe)

country.str[:5], but that only works for each column as: country['Country1'].str[:5], not for the whole DataFrame at once.

Answer (score 1):

You could remove everything after the second period, by [`replace`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.replace.html) then convert to float and round.  finally update the dataframe.

```
df.update(df.filter(regex='Country').astype(str)
  .apply(lambda x:x.str.replace(r'(\d+\.\d+).*', '\\1', regex = True))
  .astype(float).round(2))

df
              Booking_date  Country1  Country2 Country3 Country_4
0  2023-07-08T00:00:00.000       NaN       NaN   129.61     13.02
1  2023-07-89T00:00:00.000       NaN       NaN    19.74     67.52
```

Answer (score 0):

You can first filter the columns (here the Country* columns with strings), then [`extract`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.extract.html) the first part of the digit, convert to float and [`round`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.round.html), finally [`update`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.update.html) the DataFrame in place:

```
df.update(df
   # or manually list the columns here: [['Country3', 'Country 4']]
   .filter(like='Country').select_dtypes(exclude='number')
   .apply(lambda s: s.str.extract(r'^(\d+(?:\.\d*)?)', expand=False))
   .astype(float).round(2)
)
```

Alternative using a loop:

```
for col in ['Country3', 'Country 4']:
    df[col] = (df[col].str.extract(r'^(\d+(?:\.\d*)?)', expand=False)
                .astype(float).round(2)
              )
```

Updated DataFrame:

```
              Booking date  Country1  Country2 Country3 Country 4
0  2023-07-08T00:00:00.000       NaN       NaN   129.61     13.02
1  2023-07-89T00:00:00.000       NaN       NaN    19.74     67.52
```